# Manage multiple scripts on single page application

Tags: javascript, performance, cordova, single-page-application

I am developing a single page phonegap application. using my own custom logic (not using any single page library).

It have functionalities like Web Service accessing and online - offline syncing and other phonegap features.

I have almost 100 views and its code. now I came across a confusion, What is the best solution to achieve this.

I will generate html from templates stored already on my main html page.
I will also remove view's html when swapping between views.

1) merge all code in single js file.

- it may causes memory leak, and very large amount of objects as it will included in single js file.

2) Add/Remove script tag dynamically

- split Application logic in view wise js files and then dynamically add/remove script tag using jquery.
- Also remove dom event listeners added.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you using [backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/) and [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) for your project.

You can learn about backbone.js here. http://backbonetutorials.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have not heard of memory leaks on large JavaScript files. I will say that using a task runner like `grunt` will help both organization and performance. In HTTP1, requests are expensive. Until HTTP2 (that has multiplexing) comes out, combining scripts is a very good practice.